# Perl6 NativeCall cannot locate symbol in native library

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, raku, nativecall

I have a module using NativeCall that works on both Linux and macOS, but not Windows. When I try to use the module on Windows I get lots of errors like:

```
# Cannot locate symbol 'TinyTIFFReader_open' in native library 'tinytiff.dll'
```

I use cmake for my C++ dependency on all three OS's. On Linux and macOS I can just `cmake ..; make; sudo make install`, and on Windows I `cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" ..` and then open the created ".sln" in Visual Studio to compile. The build succeeds with no errors on all three OS's.

Does anyone have any ideas of what I would need to do/change to also get my module working on Windows?

The full module is located here: https://github.com/ryn1x/Graphics-TinyTIFF

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you will have to give `TINYTIFFREADER_LIB_EXPORT` and `TINYTIFFWRITER_LIB_EXPORT` defines a value (either in the source, but probably better to have it be passed by the build system) and on windows i think it has to be `__declspec(dllexport)`, otherwise the symbols may not be made available in the dll.

Comment: Thanks! Looking into your suggestion also led me to finding a solution that does not require modifying any code. On Windows you can just `cmake -DCMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS=TRUE -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=TRUE -G "Visual
Studio 15 2017 Win64" ..`